# Word web add-in works only after cleaning up the cache

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, office-js-helpers, word-web-addins

I am working on word web add-in. There are two issues which I am always facing in non development environment.

1. Sometimes word add-in displays blank screen in non-dev environments. Only after cleaning up the cache as mentioned in the below MS link, it starts working. This is really causing lot of trouble.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors
   When I check the logs, I am seeing below error,

Error: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
at exports.render (eval code:290:266)
at render (eval code:13831:9)
at eval code (eval code:13834:1)
at ./index.tsx (https://xxxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:6497:1)
at **webpack_require** (https://xxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:21:12)
at 1 (https://xxxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:6506:1)
at **webpack_require** (https://xxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:21:12)
at Anonymous function (https://xxxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:85:11)
at Global code (https://xxxxxx/app.92a88d0275783a78f955.js:2:11)

The application works fine in the browser.

2. When I keep the word add-in open for long time, my add-in crashes and getting error,
   "Sorry,  we had to restart because this add-in wasn't responding"

Please let me know how to resolve these issues.

Thanks,
Sabaresh

Comment: Which add-in are you trying to use? Does this happen with every add-in?

Comment: @AbidRahman-MSFT,  we have created a separate add-in using React Typescript. I have updated the question with the error which I am seeing. Looks like while rendering its throwing error. Its intermittent, after you click reload few times, it works fine. Please assist.